# Fix for BILLING_TRANSACTION_ERROR using Google Survey API

Tags: google-surveys

I'm using the Google API client library for PHP to create Google Surveys. I'm able to create surveys, but not start them. The error I receive is:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [domain] => global [reason] => BILLING_TRANSACTION_ERROR [message] => Billing Transaction Error: Current user is not configured for post-payment..

I've set up a billing account @ https://console.cloud.google.com/billing and see my project linked to the account, but am still getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the Google Surveys team. To start and stop surveys with the API, you'll need to have an established sales relationship with us. Please email surveys-api@google.com for more information on getting set up with that.